# Как реализовать реактивность в кастомном хуке VUE3

Tags: vue3

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно в кастомном хуке реализовать реактивное обновление компоннентво

Идея в следующем, есть сайт, который умеет переключать язык и затем обновляет localstorage.language. Я сделал хук, который выводит по локации пользователя, город и страну на языке, который уже был в localstorage.language, а если он не заполнен, то выводит название на дефолтном языке

Проблема в том, что если пользователь поменяет язык, то хочется, чтобы город и страна тоже перевелась на выбранный язык. хук выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может вообще стоит отказаться от идеи с хуком и релизовать store хранилище и там обновлять данные ?

Comment: Да лучше через store, и доступен будет везде, и в принципе работа с данными там должна быть